# Perforce depots

Tags: perforce

Is it preferred to have one depot with multiple folders which map to different paths in a workspace. OR multiple folders in one depot that map to multiple workspaces, or multiple depots to multiple workspaces.

Does anyone have any practical advice on the matter?

I've also noticed that when I have multiple folders in a depot that map to different paths in my workspace when i diff from the depot a change in one of the sub folders does not show up in the diff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the size of your depots I think it is more a question of taste. We have currently two different depots, but mainly because they are disjunctive in their nature (`//sw` vs. `//data/`). The [Perforce Knowledge Base](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2437/) says:

> The most significant difference with
>   the multiple depot configuration is
>   that, in the Perforce Server P4ROOT
>   directory, each project is stored in
>   its own top-level depot directory
>   (rather than as a subdirectory of a
>   single depot). The multiple depot
>   configuration allows you to use the
>   depot "Map" field to put each
>   top-level depot directory on a
>   separate filesystem, if desired. More
>   on using the Map field can be found in
>   the Command Reference entry for the p4
>   depot command.
>
> Performance is another consideration
>   in configuring single vs. multiple
>   depots. By splitting projects into
>   separate depots, file paths for many
>   Perforce operations are inherently
>   limited to a more narrow range of
>   files, resulting in reduced need to
>   scan certain database tables. The
>   performance difference is dependent on
>   the particular data sets and usage.
>   For many small installations, there is
>   no appreciable difference. However,
>   for larger installations and for some
>   usage environments, the performance
>   difference might be significant.